# Why can't I get Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply to work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wmi

I have some simple code:

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = 
    new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply");

ManagementObjectCollection items = searcher.Get();

foreach (ManagementObject item in items)
{
    // Some code here...
}
```

The "items" object is semi-null. It's actually an object, but a call to .Count or anything else throws an exception.

I do have a standard USB-compliant UPS hooked up, this is Windows 7, and I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on a 64-bit machine. I did add a manifest and requireAdministrator too.

Other WMI classes work, but this one doesn't. I'm out of ideas - help!

Comment: Does the base class CIM_UninterruptiblePowerSupply work any better?

Comment: @xcud - well, .Count is now 0. So I get a better response back, but it still doesn't bring back the information about the UPS. Any other ideas?? thanks!

Comment: How many instances show in wbemtest.exe?

Comment: It says "Not found" for Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply. For CIM_UninterruptiblePowerSupply, it finds it - but has 0 instances. It does show up in my Device Manager under "Batteries". The device is a CyberPower CP1500AVRLCD and is hooked up via USB cable. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well from the MSDN documentation for [Win32_UninterruptiblePowerSupply](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394503(VS.85).aspx) it states that:

> Beginning with Windows Vista, this
>   class is obsolete and not available
>   because the UPS service is no longer
>   available. This service worked with
>   serially attached UPS devices, not USB
>   devices.

Comment: Ahh - I didn't catch that, thanks! Any ideas on how I DO capture USB UPS information??

Comment: You may want to take a look at the Win32_Battery and Win32_PortableBattery classes.

Comment: Yeah - those are both empty. I never did figure out how to do this. Thanks anyhow...

Answer (score 1):

try a CIM_UninterruptiblePowerSupply:

' UPS Availability (WMI)

```
Private Function UPSavailability() As String

    Dim s As String = ""
    UPSavailability = s

    Try
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("root\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM CIM_UninterruptiblePowerSupply")

        For Each queryObj As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            s = queryObj("Availability")
        Next

        Return s

    Catch err As ManagementException
        MessageBox.Show("An error occurred while querying for WMI data: " & err.Message)
    End Try
End Function
```